# Eclipse Plugin Dependencies

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible if I have Three Eclipse plugins called A,B and C.And all are dependent on each other like A depends on B,B depends on C and C depends on A.

In Eclipse Plugin Development we generally create Extension Point that is used by other plugins as extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to give a 'circular dependency' error when you try to build as Eclipse will not be able to work out which plugin to build first.